# Cannot detect onNavigationItemSelected using Databind. How to get all menu item click in Navigationview?

Tags: android, data-binding, navigationview

I tried this code But it did not work. In my class, I have Implemented `onNavigationItemSelected`.
.I have tried this https://medium.com/@oldergod/bottomnavigationview-callback-and-and-databinding-9775b0c31d38.but this does not work
 Dashboard layout...

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
      name="navigationItemSelectedListener"
      type="al_logistics.app.com.al_logistics.Dashboard"/>
  </data>
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_manu"
 app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{navigationItemSelectedListener::onNavigationItemSelected}"
    app:menu="@menu/list_menu"/>
```

Here is my onNavigationItemSelected

```
 @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have done this.You need to implement listener otherwise it won't work.Please let me know if the solution work

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_dashboard);
binding.navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and remove this line from XML:

```
app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{navigationItemSelectedListener::onNavigationItemSelected}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that navigationItemSelectedListener asks for listener, not the actual function.
Correct way to use it would be:

```xml
app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{ menuItem -> navigationItemSelectedListener.onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem) }"
```

This way listener is created in databinding.

Other solution (as name `navigationItemSelectedListener` implies) would be for it to implement `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and then in layout

```xml
    app:navigationItemSelectedListener="@{navigationItemSelectedListener}"
```